# How to estimate $\int_0^{L/2} f(x)dx$ from $f(x)\ge 2x-\frac{L}{D} \int_0^x f(t)dt$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, integral-inequality

$D>0, L>0$ are constant. $f:[0, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is non-negative continuous function.  $f(0)=0$ and $D=\int_0^{+\infty} f(x) dx$. In fact, when $x>0$ is large enough (than $L$), there is $f(x)=0$.  If
$$
f(x)\ge 2x-\frac{L}{D} \int_0^x f(t)dt  ~~~~~~\forall x\in [0,\frac{L}{2}]  \tag{1}
$$
Then, how to show
$$
\int_0^{L/2} f(x)dx \ge CL^2   \tag{2}
$$
where $C$ is a positive constant. The reason of $(2)$ is that the problem has actual background.  In fact, I want to calculate the optimal $C$.

What I try: Integrate $(1)$, I have
$$
\int_0^{L/2} f(x)dx\ge \frac{L^2}{4}-\frac{L}{D}\int_0^{L/2}\int_0^x f(t)dt dx
$$
After exchange the order of integrate, I have
$$
\int_0^{L/2} f(x)dx\ge \frac{L^2}{4}-\frac{L}{D}\int_0^{L/2} f(t)(\frac{L}{2}-t)dt
\tag{3}
$$

Comment: You cannot differentiate an inequality.

Comment: @geetha290krm  Just feel, I really know nothing about integral-inequality.

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. Can't you just choose $C=\int_0^{L/2}f/L^2$? Are you trying to find $C$ that is independent of $L$? You have to tell us what $C$ is allowed to depend on.

Comment: @durianice  $C$ is independent of all. Just a constant,  the optimal $C$ should be  $\frac{1}{2\pi}$. But I think the above expound is not enough to get $C=\frac{1}{2\pi}$.

Comment: By setting $F(x):=\int_0^x f$ and solving the differential inequality (e.g. by integrating factor method), I got $$F(x)\geq \frac{2D}{L}x-2\frac{D^2}{L^2}+2\frac{D^2}{L^2}e^{-L^2/2D}$$, which gives (expanding the exponential into power series) a lower bound of $$C=\frac{L^2}{2}\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-L^2/2D)^{k-2}}{k!},$$which looks pretty ugly, but I can't seem to do better atm.

Comment: Typo in the last comment, the expression inside the exponential in the last display should be $-Lx/D$ instead of $-L^2/2D$.